# Trying to deploy Django without root, server can't find .fcgi file

Tags: python, django, .htaccess, virtualenv, local

I am trying to deploy Django onto an A2 Hosting VPS account without root access. I followed the directions for installation [here](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/python/installing-and-configuring-django-with-fastcgi-on-shared-hosting) except since I wasn't allowed a global `virtualenv` account. I used:

```
pip install --user virtualenv
```

And my virtual environment had to be added to **~/djangoenv** instead of the path described. I couldn't find any instructions that described how to alter install to account for this so I continued on and tried my best to substitute what I thought was right eg.paths. I added these 2 files to my **html_public**:

**.htaccess:**

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
AddHandler fcgid-script .fastcgi
RewriteEngine on
# Set up static content redirect:
RewriteRule static/(.+)$ mysite/public/static/$1
# The following two lines are for FastCGI:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ application.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

**application.fcgi:**

```
#!/home/fantasy2/.local/lib/python2.7

# Set up the virtual environment:
import os, sys
os.environ.setdefault('PATH', '/bin:/usr/bin')
os.environ['PATH'] = '/home/fantasy2/djangoenv/bin:' + os.environ['PATH']
os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV'] = '/home/fantasy2/djangoenv/bin'
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/home/fantasy2/djangoenv/bin'
os.chdir('/home/fantasy2/public_html/mysite')

# Add a custom Python path.
sys.path.insert(0, "/home/fantasy2/public_html/mysite")

# Set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable to the file in the
# application directory with the db settings etc.
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "mysite.settings"

from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
```

After adding these, it says to check the url to see the "it worked" page but I received an error:

> The requested URL /application.fcgi/ was not found on this server.

I tried to change the path in the **application.fcgi** file and several different versions of the **.htaccess** page that I found while researching the issue. I then tried to go on and finish the rest of the directions with the databases and `STATIC_URL` but this didn't help either. I have been trying to figure this out for 2 days now and also tried wiping everything from my site and starting fresh but cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that fastcgi was not configured properly, and since I didn't have root I could not fix it. I had to contact the host and have them redeploy fastcgi or possibly deploy it for the first time, not sure but it is working now after this.